# Changing SQL Server version in App_config causes server error/ - ASP.NET MVC & .NET framework 4.6?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to connect my ASP.NET MVC 4.6 application to SQL Server 2017. In the `web.config`, I have added the parameter value.

Here is the config:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="v11.0"/>
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                  type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Here is my model class -

```
namespace MusicStore.Models
{
    public class MusicStoreDataContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is another -

```
namespace MusicStore.Models
{
    /* Table name is Artist */
    [Table("Artist")]
    public class Artist
    {
        public int ArtistID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the controller -

```
public class ArtistsController : Controller
    {
        MusicStoreDataContext context = new MusicStoreDataContext();
        // GET: Artists
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(context.Artists.ToList());
        }
    }
```

I want this code first Entity Framework to create database on my SQL Server and not here. The version is v11.0. I should be able to see this on my SQL Server Management Studio. Please help.

However, I get the following error while opening -

http://localhost:55066/Artists

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 14:         public ActionResult Index()
>   Line 15:         {
>   Line 16:             return View(context.Artists.ToList());
>   Line 17:         }
>   Line 18:     }
>
> Source File: C:\Users\sjoshi\source\repos\SJ_MusicStore\MusicStore\Controllers\ArtistsController.cs    Line: 16

Comment: Can you check more details of error and post here?

Comment: I think the problem is not from web.config, because the syntax seem just fine. Can you show `DbContext` class definition, because sometimes this problem originated from a typo in connection string name?

Comment: added the other codes - model classes and controller class.